# How to add value to CodeIgniter query result?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, array-push

I am using CodeIgniter to generate some query results, and then in a second step using a foreach loop to run a method using values from the query result.  What I would like to do now is to somehow combine the new variable with the original query.  Here is the code so far:

```
$qryOriginal = $this->db->query("SELECT 1 as BAND, 
  tblappeals.Scenario, 
  tblappeals.Year, 
  tblappeals.var1, 
  tblappeals.var2 
  FROM tblappeals 
  WHERE tblappeals.Property = $pn ");

foreach ($qryOriginal->result() as $row)
{
$var3 = $this->getPhaseIn($calcyear, $row->var1, $row->var2);
    echo $var3; //HOW CAN I ADD THIS $var3 VALUE TO qryOriginal ???  
}
```

There must be an easy way to add this new value to the original query.  I just don't know how to do it.  I was thinking to use `array_push()`, but that doesn't seem to be the right function.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to add it to the "original query" or the **results** of the original query?

Comment: Hi @AymanSafadi, I would like to add it to the results of the original query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't add it to the results directly; what you *can* do is store the results in a variable, and add the contents of `$var3` to this variable.  Like this:

```
$qryOriginal = $this->db->query("SELECT 1 as BAND, 
  tblappeals.Scenario, 
  tblappeals.Year, 
  tblappeals.var1, 
  tblappeals.var2 
  FROM tblappeals 
  WHERE tblappeals.Property = $pn ");

$qryOriginalResults = $qryOriginal->result();

foreach ($qryOriginal->result() as $row)
{
    $var3 = $this->getPhaseIn($calcyear, $row->var1, $row->var2);
    $qryOriginalResults[] = $var3;
}
```

Think about it, if you where to add `$var3` to the actual results, you would create a never-ending for-loop.

Comment: This makes sense.  Let me give it a try and let you know how I make out.

Comment: Hi again @Ayman.  I still seem to be having a problem.  I am trying to get the resulting `$qryOriginalResults` into an array using `$data['mydata'] = $qryOriginalResults->result_array();` but it does not seem to be working.  What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: @DanielAttard you just need to do `$data['mydata'] = $qryOriginalResults;`

Comment: Thanks @RajeevRanjan, I tried your suggestion but I don't see the new `$var3` being added to the original `$qryOriginalResults`.  When I output the array, I don't see the new value.

Comment: @DanielAttard, what do you mean by *"not working"*? Do a `var_dump` on both `$qryOriginalResults` and `$var3`. Take a look and tell me what's wrong...

Answer (score 1):

```
  $qryOriginal = $this->db->query("SELECT 1 as BAND, 
  tblappeals.Scenario, 
  tblappeals.Year, 
  tblappeals.var1, 
  tblappeals.var2 
  FROM tblappeals 
  WHERE tblappeals.Property = $pn ");

$qryOriginalResults = $qryOriginal->result_array();
//result() gives result object
foreach ($qryOriginalResults as $row)
{
    $var3 = $this->getPhaseIn($calcyear, $row['var1'], $row['var2']);
    $qryOriginalResults[] = $var3;
}
$data['mydata'] = $qryOriginalResults;
```